# Facebook OAuth on Android

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, oauth

Every time I test out my app on the emulator. "An error occurred with AppName. Please try again later." I have enabled internet access in the manifest .XML.

This is what I have so far:

```
package com.xxxxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;

public class LunchtimeActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new String [] {"user_location", "friend_location", "user_events", "friends_events"}, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString( "fields", "id,name" ); 

        try {
            String response = facebook.request( "me/friends", parameters ); 

            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson( response );

            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray( "data" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject friend = data.getJSONObject( i );

                String id = friend.getString( "id" );
                String name = friend.getString( "name" );
                Log.v("JSON", id);
                Log.v("JSON", name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        catch (FacebookError f) {}

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

[image]

Logcat output:

```
...
05-01 02:21:01.601: DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(234): Webview loading URL: fbconnect://success/?error=invalid_scope&error_description=Unsupported+scope%3A+%27friend_location...
```

Eclipse console output:

```
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] ------------------------------
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] Android Launch!
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] Performing com.lunch.LunchtimeActivity activity launch
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Now' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-05-01 02:18:57 - Lunchtime_1.0] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Now'
[2011-05-01 02:19:03 - Emulator] 2011-05-01 02:19:03.471 emulator[3575:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-05-01 02:19:03 - Lunchtime_1.0] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-01 02:19:03 - Lunchtime_1.0] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-05-01 02:20:20 - Lunchtime_1.0] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-05-01 02:20:20 - Lunchtime_1.0] Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1-update1)
[2011-05-01 02:20:20 - Lunchtime_1.0] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-01 02:20:20 - Lunchtime_1.0] Uploading Lunchtime_1.0.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-01 02:20:20 - Lunchtime_1.0] Installing Lunchtime_1.0.apk...
[2011-05-01 02:20:39 - Lunchtime_1.0] Success!
[2011-05-01 02:20:39 - Lunchtime_1.0] Starting activity com.lunch.LunchtimeActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-05-01 02:20:43 - Lunchtime_1.0] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.lunch/.LunchtimeActivity }
```

I'm literally just using the Facebook SDK provided by Facebook itself for Android and I can't make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: `04-30 13:49:54.680: WARN/LauncherProvider(143): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}`

Comment: also `04-30 13:49:58.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(160): ERROR: thread attach failed`

Comment: there's actually a lot of crap that comes out of logcat, those just seemed like the most helpful one

Comment: This doesn't seem related. find the error that is printed when you get the crash.

Comment: I found this one: `04-30 13:50:19.687: WARN/ResourceType(66): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5` but I don't really know....what type of error should I be looking for?

Comment: Not really helpful. clear the log and retry, then upload the whole log to a site like this one and give us a link to it: http://codeviewer.org/upload

Comment: good idea, I put the logcat and console output on codeviewer.org, the links are in my original (now edited) post

Comment: @lollercoaster nothing in the logcat you uploaded seems to be related to your app.

Comment: @lollercoaster - I added the logcat and eclipse log to your post. but as Aleadam said, it doesn't seem to be related to your program.

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1a1d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `friend_location` instead of `friends_location`

Check the last lines of the logcat:

> 05-01 02:21:01.601: DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(234): Webview loading URL: fbconnect://success/?error=invalid_scope&error_description=Unsupported+scope%3A+%27friend_location...

BTW, it is a good idea to add at least some log output to `public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}` and `catch (Exception e) {} catch (FacebookError f) {}`. It will save you (and us) a lot of time :)

Comment: wow thank you. im a little emabarrassed at my silliness. thanks for pointing that out. i actually played around more with logcat, the custom filters make things much easier - before I was just scrolling through everything (took forever). thanks for the fix and the tips :)

Comment: @Lollercoaster it's just a typo, no need to be embarrased :) But the lesson here is: **there is a reason to have catch blocks! Don't just ignore them.**